# Using OpenLayers how can I Extract some information relative to the whole KML file?

Tags: openlayers-2, kml

I am creating a KML layer like this:

```
new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
                projection: myDisplayProjection,
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                    url: myKmlUrl,
                    format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                        extractStyles: true,
                        extractAttributes: true
                    })
                })
            });
```

I am extracting styles and attributes.

I have some attributes attached to the document (as well as the placemarks/features).

Will this information be on the resultant layer (I think not) or how do I get this information other wise?

The information relevant to the whole layer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Aha.  It looks like somebody has tried to do what I wanted:

https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/536

He puts it better than me:

"Currently, name, description, author and other attributes of KML elements Document and Folder are ignored silently."

Looks like that is still true in the version of OpenLayers I am using (Release 2.13 dev I think).

So the version of OpenLayers I am using doesn't quite do what I want (and I don't know how to use git hub, nor do I understand when if ever this code was/will be released), but I might be able to hack a solution at my end using this nice man's code.

Thanks jachym and aragon

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get attributes of your kml layer, try out this code with SelectFeature:

```
onSelect: function(f){
var feat = f.attributes;
var keys = [];
for(var key in feat){
    keys.push([key , feat[key]])
};

for(var a=0; a<keys.length; a++){
    fInfo += '<b>' + keys[a][0] + '</b> : ' + keys[a][1] + '<br>' 
}
fInfo = fInfo.replace('undefined', '');

}
```

it will give you result as following output.

> **name**: Sundial, Nidai, Lithunia
>
> **description**: A large horizantal sundial.
>
> **styleUrl**: #msn_sunny_copy70

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Thanks.  In your example, f is a feature, correct?  Features are equivalent to the Placemarks in a KML file, right?  All my Placemarks are in a Document node.  I want to be able to get to data directly under the Document node (or a better palace should it exist).  I think you are allowed to give it a name, description, ExtendedData etc.  I want to know how to get to that information.  It is probably lost when parsed, in which case, I want to know if there still a reference to the raw KML which I could then parse myself.

Comment: I am basically trying to create KML files that contain all the information needed to be understood (a title, a legend), and avoid multiple hits to get the same bit of information.  If a Placemark is equivalent to a feature, what is the appropriate place to put information relating to the layer?

Comment: i didnt change anything from raw kml.

Comment: Sorry?  A kml file has multiple placemarks.  In my case, these are polygons.  Each polygon has some data associated with it.  I have no problem getting to that data (I can uses the description field, and in javascript it will be at feature.attributes.description).  What I want is to get to some data that is at the document level (outside a feature).  Data relevant to the whole "layer" not just a selected feature.

Comment: AFAIK It is not possible. Until recently I used a patched code of KML.js to retrieve the `<Document><name>` as name at the first feature without geometry. (not very pretty, but it worked)